# AngulaJS input fields not loose focus when clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus

I am trying to create a simple angularjs form where i want to have nested object as ng-model

```
$scope.project = {
   name:"Some Name",
   location:{line1:"" , line2:"", city:"", zipcode:""}
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RfN7qZBX3HlOtGhFOdFX?p=preview

now the problem is when i click on line2 , city,state etc focus goes back to line1 
tried changing HTML and several other stuff but don't know what to do.. 
Tried removing bootstrap as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are misusing the `<label>` tag. Instead of this:

```
<label class="form-group">
     Client Location
     <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.line1" class="form-control" placeholder="Line 1">
         <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.line2" class="form-control" placeholder="Line 2">
         <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
         <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.state" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
         <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.zip" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code">
         <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.country" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
      </div>
  </label>
```

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Client Location</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.line1" class="form-control" placeholder="Line 1">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.line2" class="form-control" placeholder="Line 2">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.state" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.zip" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.location.country" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
    </div>
</div>
```

The first label should be changed as well. Instead of this:

```
<label class="form-group">Name
     <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
     </div>
</label>
```

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<div  class="form-group">
  <label>
    Name
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="project.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that works.. i added label tag for single field to avoid use of IDs. if input is inside label you dont need to map ID automatically. forgot to avoid it for multiple fields.. thanks a lot

Comment: I think for single field i would still use Label tag as i prefer to have accessibility and dont want to use id for every input. Do you have any suggestion to take care of this situation

Comment: I've added an alternative that wraps the <input> in a <label>.